# How to get arguments that either are or are not surrounded by quotes using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find the best way to get arguments out of a string.

The string could look like: `"exArg1" exArg2 "exArg3 with space" exArg4 exArg5`

And I want the matches to be placed in a string list with 5 entries `"exArg1" "exArg2" "exArg3 with space" "exArg4" "exArg5"`

I have code that first finds the arguments surrounded by strings, then finds the arguments not surrounded by strings, which is working

```
public static List<String> getArgs(String args){
    List<String> argList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Get all arguments surrounded by quotes
    String regex = "\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"\\s*";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher match   = pattern.matcher(args);

    while (match.find())
    {
        if (match.groupCount() != 0)
        {
            if (match.group(1) != null)
            {
                argList.add(match.group(1));
                args = args.replaceAll(match.group(), " ");
                match = pattern.matcher(args);
            }
        }
    }

    //Get all arguments not surrounded by quotes
    regex = "\\s*([^\"\\s]+)\\s*";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    match   = pattern.matcher(args);

    while (match.find())
    {
        if (match.groupCount() != 0)
        {
            if (match.group(1) != null)
            {
                argList.add(match.group(1));
            }
        }
    }

    return argList;
}
```

But I want to know if there is a better way to combine both cases into one regex. I thought I could simply OR them as so: `"[\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"\\s*]|[\\s*([^\"\\s]+)\\s*]"` but that does not work (it matches on the first " in my example, and from there everything after is wrong)

Comment: Use [`"([^"]*)"|\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/t38GEP/2) and check if Group 1 is not null. If it is not, grab `group(1)`, else, grab `group(0)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! That works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not have escaped entities in the command line arguments (no escaped quotes) you may use a single regex to match both quoted and unquoted arguments with [`"([^"]*)"|\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/t38GEP/2) regex. Check if Group 1 is not *null* and if it is not, grab `group(1)`, else, grab `group(0)`.

To support escaped double quotes, use `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|\S+` regex.

Sample [Java code](http://ideone.com/lUr1dA):

```
String str = "\"exArg1\" \"exArg2\" \"exArg3 with space\" exArg4 \"exArg5\"";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"|\\S+"); 
// Or "\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\"|\\S+" to support escaped quotes
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) == null) {
        result.add(matcher.group(0));
    } else {
        result.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
System.out.println(result); // => [exArg1, exArg2, exArg3 with space, exArg4, exArg5]
```