# Split with Regex before sequence appears

Tags: javascript, java, regex, readfile, to-json

I have a text file with following content:

Test, [636,13,"be738jsk","some, text",js]

I want to read this content into an Array. I currently use JavaScript with regex to split into substrings directly into an array.
As regex i have:
`line.split(/,\s\[|",|,"|","/);`

The problem is, i have some sentences like in the example with a "," in it and i don't want to split there. So i tried to say in the regex, "split after , and everthing except whitespace". The problem is, it also cuts out the "everything" after the ,

Example:

Test, [63737,33,"bla,blablba",737]

When i use this regex:

`Line.split(/,"|,\s\[|",|,[^\s]/);`
Then it cut's out the 3 from 33 :(

Comment: Try just `string.match(/\w+|"[^"]*"/g)` or `Array.from('Test, [636,13,"be738jsk","some, text",js]'.matchAll(/\w+|"([^"]*)"/g), x => x[1] ?? x[0])`

Comment: Your second solution works perfectly. Thx. But now I detected, that there also some strings like "[Blablba] Blablba". With your solution sadly this also get splitted :/ So have a solution for this

Comment: `Array.from("[Blablba] Blablba".matchAll(/\w+|"([^"]*)"/g), x => x[1] ?? x[0])` shows `['Blablba', 'Blablba']`, is it not expected?

Comment: No because the [Blabla] Blabla is between two quotation marks and should stay together.

Comment: Then my solution still works, see the answer below with a code demo.

Comment: Oh yes thx. Last question: When i have in the string a substring, like: Test, [1726,12,"[Header] nice one "Test" bla",15]. Currently it splits the hole string because of the quotation marks in it. Is there also a solution for this? Combined with the solution from before?

Comment: What do you expect to get as a result? Do you mean there is a missing `"`?

Comment: When i have: Test, [2637,12,"[Blablba] nice "Test" one",637] I want to have an array with my String in one field: [ [Blablba] nice "Test" one] without splitting. With your latest solution sadly this gets splitted Into: [ [Blablba] nice, test, one]. You know what i mean? :)

Comment: I only know what you write, and what you have supplied is `Test, [2637,12,"[Blablba] nice "Test" one",637]`. And this means you have double quotes inside double quotes. And there is no solution for this. It looks like some buggy output from some data provider, and it should be fixed on their side. Or, do you mean the double quotes inside double quotes are escaped? Please use backticks when adding examples or code inside comments.

Comment: Hey can you maybe tell me how to do the same in normal Java? :)

Comment: [Here is the sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41968628/3832970), where `\S` is used instead of `\w`, so just replace `\S` with `\w`, and it will work.

Comment: It works, thank you. But currently if I have a number in my string like ```Test, ["Blabla",3.0, -1.0``` sadly it's giving out: ```..."3", "0", "1", "0"``` Do you have any solution for this to put in my Regex? :/

Comment: Yes, `/[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\w+|"([^"]*)"/g` or `/[-+]?\d*\.?\d+|\w+|"([^"]*)"/g`

Comment: Thank you so so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = 'Test, [636,13,"be738jsk","some, text",js], "[Blablba] Blablba"';
console.log(
  Array.from(text.matchAll(/\w+|"([^"]*)"/g), x => x[1] ?? x[0])
)
```

Output:

```
[
  "Test",
  "636",
  "13",
  "be738jsk",
  "some, text",
  "js",
  "[Blablba] Blablba"
]
```

Here, `\w+|"([^"]*)"` matches one or more word chars or any zero or more chars other than double quotation marks (captured into Group 1) in between double quotation marks. The `x => x[1] ?? x[0]` part takes Group 1 values if defined, else, it keeps the whole match value.